# Appending an existing returned array to an existing array

Tags: php, laravel

Working with a database that has a table and fields such as

album

```
id
titleId
titleName
```

track

```
id
titleId
trackId
trackName
```

artist

```
id
artistId
```

track_log

```
id
artistId
titleId
```

in this case mutiple artists can own a track, and there can be multiple tracks on an album.

Using a model I am able to return all tracks for an album like so

```
public function track() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Album', 'titleId', 'titleId');
}
```

So I am now able to use $album->track to pull all tracks on that album.

It would return

```
{
"id": 1,
"titleId": 3,
"titleName": "Why so hard?",
},
```

I am looking for a way to highlight the tracks on the album that artist worked on by appending the artistId on to the results for the track in the model? Something along the lines as

```
trackHighlightArtist()
```

So that that would return something such as:

```
{
"id": 1,
"titleId": 3,
"titleName": "Why so hard?",
"artistId": 4,
},
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you defined the relationship between the track and the artist yet somewhere?

Comment: Using relation you can't find this type of array, relation gives you array and inner array. Using laravel query builder and join table, you can find this type of array.

Comment: I'm sorry I was looking to reedit. There is a table in which the two intersect. So each artist has a log of tracks. That table contains the id, the artist  id, and the title id. I had not defined a relationship yet, but I assume that would be hasMany as well?

Comment: Try API Resource collections.
[Laravel Resource Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see from your previous reply that you have a way of getting highlighted tracks. If you dont, create a relationship to get if then you can push it into your collection using `$collection->push(['key' => 'value'])` [pushing into laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-push)